# -[Not A Type retain]: message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: ios, ios5, automatic-ref-counting

I have converted my app to use ARC.

Before I had the following line of code:

```
NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:startColor, endColor, nil];
```

Since the implicit conversion of a non-Objective-C pointer type to 'id' is disallowed with ARC, I rewrote the line like this:

```
NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(__bridge id)startColor, (__bridge id)endColor, nil];
```

Everything works fine on the simulator, however on the device the app crashes on the mentioned line with the error message:

```
-[Not A Type retain]: message sent to deallocated instance
```

Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: what types are your variable? surrounding code would be fine to determine if you need `__bridge`, `__bridge_retained` or `__bridge_transfer`

Comment: The types of the variables are CGColorRef. I am not sure what you mean by "surrounding code", but I have tried all 3 versions of "__bridge" however the problem persists.

Comment: how do you create the CGColorRef? do you release it?..

Comment: I create it like this: `CGColorRef startColor = xColor.CGColor;` where xColor is of type UIColor in the parent classes. Should I retain it?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This bridged cast may not work, as hatfinch describes in [his answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8155844/cg-gradient-runs-on-simulator-but-not-on-iphone/8159523#8159523), because the CGColorRef returned from `-CGColor` may not hang around after your last reference to the UIColor that generates it.  I thought this was a bug, based on the discussion in [this Apple developer forum thread](https://devforums.apple.com/message/550670), but it was a misreading of how to manage the lifetime of these CGColorRefs.

One way that this will work is to use the built-in bridging provided by the `-CGColor` method on UIColor.  Rather than saving out your CGColor to a temporary variable as you do above, you should be able to use something like the following:

```
NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[color1 CGColor],
                                            (id)[color2 CGColor], nil];
```

with `color1` and `color2` being UIColor instances.

The bridging is taken care of for you by the `-CGColor` method, according to the "The Compiler Handles CF Objects Returned From Cocoa Methods" section of the [Transitioning to ARC Release Notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/_index.html).  The documentation is currently missing the cast to id that I have above, which is required to get this to compile.

I've tested this, and it seems to work in my case, matching what Ben reports in the above-linked Developer Forums thread.

In addition to the above, you can explicitly retain and release the CGColorRefs returned from the `-CGColor` method and bridge them across in your NSArray, again as hatfinch shows [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8155844/cg-gradient-runs-on-simulator-but-not-on-iphone/8159523#8159523).

Comment: That's correct. I had solved this problem myself in exactly the same way, but couldn't answer my own question due to the StackOverflow restriction (responding to your own question several hours after posting it). Thanks!

Comment: You saved my day. I've been tearing my hair out for hours over this.

Comment: Thanks to you, I didn't have to tear my hair out like Jason!

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
If you use UIColor's CGColor property, the CGColor will go away the moment you last reference the UIColor instance. To avoid this, "bridge" your colors directly in the function call:

```
NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[uiStartColor CGColor], [uiEndColor CGColor], nil];
```

This method is described in [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226-CH1-DontLinkElementID_5)

Original:
try assigning a variable: `id color = (__bridge_transfer id)CGColorCreate(...);` and do nothing else with the direct return value of CGColorCreate()

Comment: I tried `id color = (__bridge_transfer id)CGColorCreateCopy(...);` however it does not help

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Brad for the tip of -CGColor!

my app crash on following line, which will be invoked by a NSInvocation object.

```
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);
```

the workaround is defining a color property and use it instead.

```
    @property(strong, nonatomic) UIColor *backgroundColor;
    ......
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    ......
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, self.backgroundColor.CGColor);
```