# CGColorRef causing crash

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-graphics

I've had a crash in my code, and I've tracked it all the way back to a line crashing when being passed 2 CGColorRefs. Here are the objects:

```
CGColorRef startColor = [[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.92 alpha:1.0]CGColor];
CGColorRef endColor = [[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.94 alpha:1.0]CGColor];

NSLog(@"start: %@ end: %@", startColor, endColor);
```

The NSLog returns a crash. What's wrong with them?

EDIT - where it's crashing:

```
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGFloat locations[] = { 0.0, 1.0 };
NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(__bridge_transfer id)startColor, (__bridge_transfer id)endColor, nil];
```

Comment: What exception is thrown? This runs fine for me

Comment: Please provide exception details, including the errant line itself--not just the parameters you're passing.

Comment: Edited with where it's crashing, if i don't put an NSLog there.

Comment: It gives me EXC_BAD_ACCESS, too.

Comment: This is a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8155844/cg-gradient-runs-on-simulator-but-not-on-iphone

Answer (score 13, accepted):

ARC. ARC. ARC.  UIColor->CGCOlor is one of ARC's big gotchas...

See a deep dive here:

http://weblog.bignerdranch.com/?p=296

And I wrote up some general best practices for ARC (including your problem) here:

http://amattn.com/2011/12/07/arc_best_practices.html

Comment: I know this is a few months old now, but thanks so much for this. I spent the last 4 hours trying to wrap my head around just what the heck was going on.

Comment: No prob!  I always love to hear that stuff I write helps people.

Comment: I have a similar problem, however it's not crashing on the device, it just isn't working. I'm trying to crop an image using a category. Simulator's fine and device shows full image. Using ARC. Could this problem be related ?

Comment: Two things. 1: the Big Nerd Ranch link is dead. 2: Since this is a link-only answer, the summary is to use `__autoreleasing` qualifier on symbol holding return value of UIColor class methods.