# Core Graphics Pattern crashes (only on the device)

Tags: ios, core-graphics, design-patterns, quartz-2d

I have a Core graphics Pattern that works perfectly on the simulator, but it crashes on the device:

```
void MyDrawColoredPattern4 (void *info, CGContextRef context) {
   UIColor* colorClar = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.57 green: 0.57 blue: 0.57 alpha: 1];
   UIColor* colorFosc = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.15 green: 0.15 blue: 0.15 alpha: 1];

   CGColorRef dotColor = colorFosc.CGColor;
   CGColorRef shadowColor = colorClar.CGColor;

   CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 5, -0.5);
   CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 1.1, 1.75);
   CGContextAddLineToPoint(context,1.1, 6.25);
   CGContextAddLineToPoint(context,5, 8.5);
   CGContextAddLineToPoint(context,8.9, 6.25);
   CGContextAddLineToPoint(context,8.9, 1.75);
   CGContextClosePath(context);

   CGContextMoveToPoint(context,16, 10.5);
   CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 12.1, 12.75);
   CGContextAddLineToPoint(context,12.1, 17.25);
   CGContextAddLineToPoint(context,16, 19.5);
   CGContextAddLineToPoint(context,19.9, 17.25);
   CGContextAddLineToPoint(context,19.9, 12.75);
   CGContextClosePath(context);

   CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, dotColor);
   CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context, CGSizeMake(1, 1), 2, shadowColor);

   CGContextFillPath (context);
}
```

The pattern size is 25*25 and it's filling the whole rect with `drawRect`. I know that sometimes with high requirement graphics apps tend to crash on the device and no the simulator, but I'm not sure if that's the case.

I've created some simpler patterns and they do work ok in both the simulator and the device.

Anyone?

**EDIT**: by the way, there is nothing on the console but the following in the editor area:

```
libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend:
0x37be7f68:  teq.w  r0, #0
0x37be7f6c:  beq    0x37be7faa               ; objc_msgSend + 66
0x37be7f6e:  push.w {r3, r4}
0x37be7f72:  ldr    r4, [r0]
0x37be7f74:  lsr.w  r9, r1, #2
0x37be7f78:  ldr    r3, [r4, #8]      ------------------> this line is highligthed in green.
0x37be7f7a:  add.w  r3, r3, #8
0x37be7f7e:  ldr    r12, [r3, #-8]
0x37be7f82:  and.w  r9, r9, r12
0x37be7f86:  ldr.w  r4, [r3, r9, lsl #2]
0x37be7f8a:  teq.w  r4, #0
0x37be7f8e:  add.w  r9, r9, #1
0x37be7f92:  beq    0x37be7fa6               ; objc_msgSend + 62
0x37be7f94:  ldr.w  r12, [r4]
0x37be7f98:  teq.w  r1, r12
0x37be7f9c:  bne    0x37be817e               ; objc_msgSendSuper_stret + 34
0x37be7f9e:  ldr.w  r12, [r4, #8]
0x37be7fa2:  pop    {r3, r4}
0x37be7fa4:  bx     r12
0x37be7fa6:  pop    {r3, r4}
0x37be7fa8:  b      0x37be7fb0               ; objc_msgSend_uncached
0x37be7faa:  mov.w  r1, #0
0x37be7fae:  bx     lr
```

Comment: Are you using ARC? It could be the [well-known issue with UIColor and CGColorRef](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9762969/cgcolorref-causing-crash).

Comment: Yep, that was it. I crashed again but it was because I was forgetting one color. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Write an answer so that I can mark it as the one.

Comment: Glad that fixed it. Let's just call this a duplicate of the previous -- this question doesn't add anything extra, really. (The fact that you were drawing a pattern was just a red herring.)