# Drawing a gradient as view's background without subclassing

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-graphics

I am using method [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/844710/make-background-of-uiview-a-gradient-without-sub-classing) to set a gradient background for vanilla `UIView` instance without creating a subclass. However the view comes out completely black. Here's my code:

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 315.0f, 44.0f)];

CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, 315.0, 44.0f, 8, 4 * 315, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst);

// Colors only for debugging purposes
CGColorRef startColor = (__bridge CGColorRef)[UIColor greenColor];
CGColorRef endColor = (__bridge CGColorRef)[UIColor redColor];
CFMutableArrayRef colors = CFArrayCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, 2, &kCFTypeArrayCallBacks);
CFArrayAppendValue(colors, startColor);
CFArrayAppendValue(colors, endColor);

CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorSpace, colors, (const CGFloat []){0.25f, 0.75f});

CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, CGPointZero, CGPointMake(0.0f, 44.0f), 0);

CGImageRef cgImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);

UIImage *backgroundGradient = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage];
[view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:backgroundGradient]];

CFRelease(colors);
CGGradientRelease(gradient);
CGImageRelease(cgImage);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
CGContextRelease(context);
return view;
```

I believe something might be wrong with the allocation of context since the created images are returned of desired size (315x44). What did I miss? What else can I check that would help me debug this problem?

Comment: Why do you not want to create a subclass?

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you get a `CGColorRef` you need to do

```
[UIColor redColor].CGColor
```

Comment: That's another problem - I get a crash (using ARC) on those lines. No idea why.

Comment: You don't need this cast `(__bridge CGColorRef)`. Also check the answer here for potential ARC issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8155844/cg-gradient-runs-on-simulator-but-not-on-iphone