# Getting -[Not A Type retain]: message sent to deallocated instance post ARC changes

Tags: objective-c, ios

We have made the changes to our objective-c code as required by the transition to ARC. But now some code we have to draw on screen is not working.

We are getting: "-[Not A Type retain]: message sent to deallocated instance" against this line:

```
NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(__bridge id)startColor,
                                            (__bridge id)endColor, nil];
```

The local debug window shows that it is "startColor". startColor is a CGColorRef type and I cannot see it being de-allocated anywhere.

Comment: Have you looked at the answer to this question already for an idea?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7993516/not-a-type-retain-message-sent-to-deallocated-instance

Answer (score 0):

Try "_*bridge*_retained" instead of "__bridge"